# What is the best way for data movement between seperate dedicated sql pools in synapse?

Tags: pyspark, azure-synapse

Can anyone tell me the best way to read data from synapse dedicated sql pool tables in synapse notebooks? My requirement is to read selected columns from tables present in two separate dedicated pools, apply some transformations, and then write to another table in one of the dedicated pools.

Answer (score 0):

The **Azure Synapse Dedicated SQL Pool Connector for Apache Spark** in Azure Synapse Analytics enables efficient transfer of large data sets between the Apache Spark runtime and the Dedicated SQL pool. The connector is shipped as a default library with Azure Synapse Workspace. The connector is implemented using Scala language. The connector supports Scala and Python. To use the Connector with other notebook language choices, use the Spark magic command - `%%spark`.

At a high-level, the connector provides the following capabilities:

**Read from Azure Synapse Dedicated SQL Pool:**

- Read large data sets from Synapse Dedicated SQL Pool Tables (Internal and External) and Views.
- Comprehensive predicate push down support, where filters on DataFrame get mapped to corresponding SQL predicate push down.
- Support for column pruning.

**Write to Azure Synapse Dedicated SQL Pool:**

- Ingest large volume data to Internal and External table types.
- Supports following DataFrame save mode preferences:

  - Append
  - ErrorIfExists
  - Ignore
  - Overwrite
- Write to External Table type supports Parquet and Delimited Text file format (example - CSV).
- To write data to internal tables, the connector now uses COPY statement instead of CETAS/CTAS approach.
- Enhancements to optimize end-to-end write throughput performance.
- Introduces an optional call-back handle (a Scala function argument) that clients can use to receive post-write metrics.

Refer: [Azure Synapse Dedicated SQL Pool Connector for Apache Spark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/synapse-spark-sql-pool-import-export?tabs=scala%2Cpython1%2Cscala2%2Cscala3%2Cscala4%2Cscala5)